# Is it possible to get history of my computer details like RAM?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building, ramdisk, parameters

I gave my PC to an agency which repairs computers. I remember that my computer had 8GB of RAM and when get back my computer has 4GB of RAM

Is it possible to retrieve a history on the size of the RAM over time?

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the make and model of the laptop? What OS are you using? Chances are you can’t easily retrieve this stuff. Maybe boot up logs can show RAM from one reboot to another. But my simple guess is one of the RAM modules is not registering. Perhaps it was loose after the repair and only one is showing up properly? Remember: Don’t attribute malice to what could just be an accident or — honestly — stupidity on the repair shop’s part.

Answer (score -1):

There is no guaranteed, universal way to do this and no standardized system log of component history, although as @Giacomo1968 has stated systems often leave hints behind in logs and the like.

A few OEM's (I particularly like Dell and their service tag system) come with a unique identifier or model variant that can be used to look at the state of the hardware as shipped by the manufacturer.